# Golang ограничение в 6 подключений

Tags: многопоточность, сервер, golang

Я создал свой Database Connections Pool для mongodb:

```
type dbcp struct {
    sync.Mutex
    connections map[*mongo.Client]struct{}
}
```

3 основные функции для работы с `dbcp`:

```
func newDBConnection() *mongo.Client {
    // Возвращает новое соединение
}

func getDBConnection() *mongo.Client {
    if len(dbcp.connections) {
        // Если пул не пустой, возвращает соединение из пула
    }
    // Если пул пустой, возвращает новое соединение:
    return newDBConnection():
}

func (c *mongo.Client) release() {
    // Добавляет соединение в пул и устанавливает таймаут
    // закрытия этого соединения и удаления из пула
}
```

Каждый запрос к, условно, `/test?id=123` открывает соединение, получает данные по `id=123` из базы данных, отправляет соединение в пул методом `c.release()`

Не важно, сколько запросов приходит одновременно - 1000, 2000 или 10000, соединений в пуле никогда не бывает больше 6 на моём компьютере. Правильно ли я понимаю, что каждый запрос, который в `Go` обрабатывается в горутине, блокирует один поток? Я всегда думал, что горутины сами переключаются, если ожидают операцию ввода-вывода (то есть не блокируются). Если это так, то как с этим работать? Как сделать сервер, чтобы поддерживал большое количество соединений одновременно?

UPD: Проверил на `Node.js` - соединений всё также 6, хотя язык интерпретируется в однопоточной среде.

Comment: а как именно проходит тест ? с браузера открываете?

Comment: @KoVadim из консоли браузера `for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) { ... }`. В целе цикла каждые 32 или 64 итерации запускаю цикл ожидания созданных промисов, потому что, как я знаю, браузер (хром) выбрасывает ошибки, если очень много одновременно подключений. Да, получается не 1000 подключений, но всё же, 6 - далеко от установленных 64. А вы хотите сказать, что браузер может искуственно ограничивать количество соединений и стоит проверить другим средством?

Comment: именно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser 
а тестить нужно хотя бы тем же ab

Comment: @KoVadim да, спасибо большое, очень помогли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современные браузеры ограничивают кол-во подключений к одному хосту. И в большинстве случаев это кол-во равно 6.  В вопросе на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) люди собрали целую подборку.

Как же потестить? можно попробовать открыть несколько страниц и/или браузеров. А можно использовать специализированные тулы, например [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) (но гуглить лучше по словам ab apache).

А еще можно написать в баш скрипте. Где то так

```
for i in {1..100}; do curl -s "http://mysite/test" &; done
```

обратите внимание на амперсанд - он заставляет не ждать окончания выполнения задачи и будет запускать сведущую. Да, это совсем на коленке, но для простого тестирования - то что нужно.